# GNU date: truncate provided date-time and set provided hours

Tags: date

I have a timestamp value in a variable and I need to truncate the hours from it and set different hours. Can GNU date do this in one go? It definitely does this for special dates like "today", "tomorrow" or "yesterday", but I can't make it use arithmetic with arbitrary timestamp:

```
$ date -d"tomorrow 10:05"
Thu Jul 23 10:05:00     2020

il@mar2 ~
$ date -d"yesterday 10:05"
Tue Jul 21 10:05:00     2020

$ date -d"@1595413447"
Wed Jul 22 13:24:07     2020

il@mar2 ~
$ date -d"@1595413447 10:05"
date: invalid date '@1595413447 10:05'
# desired: Wed Jul 22 10:05:00     2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `date` doesn't allow any additional specifications to a timestamp.

From the `date` info documentation:

> If you precede a number with ‘@’, it represents an internal timestamp as
> a count of seconds.  The number can contain an internal decimal point
> (either ‘.’ or ‘,’); any excess precision not supported by the internal
> representation is truncated toward minus infinity.  **Such a number cannot
> be combined with any other date item, as it specifies a complete
> timestamp.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

I'm afraid you need two invocations, such as

```
date -d "$(date -d @1595413447 +'%F 10:05')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always specify the time as part of the output format:

```
$ date -d @1595413447 '%a %b %e 10:05:00    %Y'
Wed Jul 22 10:05:00    2020
```

Or more portably (avoiding the GNU `date` dependency) in the `ksh93` shell:

```
$ printf '%(%a %b %e 10:05:00    %Y)T\n' '#1595413447'
Wed Jul 22 10:05:00    2020
```

Though `ksh93` also supports:

```
$ printf '%(%a %b %e %T    %Y)T\n' '#1595413447 10:05'
Wed Jul 22 10:05:00    2020
```

Or in the `zsh` shell:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime '%a %b %e 10:05:00    %Y' 1595413447
Wed Jul 22 10:05:00    2020
```

Or in the `bash` shell (`bash` copied `ksh93`'s `printf %T` for formatting but not for date parsing):

```
$ printf '%(%a %b %e 10:05:00    %Y)T\n' 1595413447
Wed Jul 22 10:05:00    2020
```